# Tkinter exit error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to get a code right but somehow it gets wrong.
My code is the following below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def show():
    p=password.get()
    o=open('C:\Working\Documents\Aditya\Write To.txt', "w+")
    o.write(p)
    o.close()
    time.sleep(2)
    app.exit()

app = Tk()
password = StringVar() #Password variable
passEntry = Entry(app, textvariable=password, show='*', width="40").pack()
submit = Button(app, text='OK',command=show, width="20")
submit.pack()
app.geometry("400x400")


app.mainloop()
```

and the error I get is :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Working\Documents\Aditya\Password.py", line 10, in show
app.exit()
File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1722, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: exit
```

if you can please help me.

Comment: Please [edit] to fix your indentation.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong -- you are trying to call a method that doesn't exist.